# How do i chnage submit button text inside mvc3 on condition?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have mvc 3 application in which i'm having one input form on Index.cshtml view. also having one webgrid which is having edit,delete button

depending upon these action links i need to change my submit button text. how can i achieve this inside homecontroller.cs ? using only one view for all edit,insert.

checking useraction inside homecontroller.cs

```
public ActionResult Index(string userAction)
    {
       if (userAction == "Edit" )
        {

        }


        if (userAction == "Delete" )
        {

        }

    }
```

View code.

```
<p>
            <input type="submit" value="Insert" />
</p>
```

On webgrid having link for edit , delete 
on that condition i need to change submit button text.

```
@if (grid != null)
    {
        @grid.GetHtml(
                    tableStyle: "grid",
                    headerStyle: "head",
                    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                    columns: grid.Columns(
                                                grid.Column("", header: null, format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Index", new { uid = (int)item.id, userAction = "Edit" })
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Index", new { uid = (int)item.id, userAction="Delete" }, new { @class = "Delete" })</text>),
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the `userAction` in `ViewData` or `ViewBag` and access it from the View.

```
public ActionResult Index(string userAction)
{
    ViewBag.UserAction = userAction;
}


<input type="submit" value="@(ViewBag.UserAction == "X" ? "Y" : "Z")" />
```

Comment: but 1st time useraction is null and submit button text should be '`insert` plz help'

Comment: I did like this 
`<input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="@(ViewBag.UserAction == "Edit" ? "Edit" : "Insert")" />`

when i run application it is insert as useraction is null. when it is edit text is edit. need only 2 conditions is it ok??